# Docker compose volume on external drive windows 10

Tags: windows, docker-compose, volume

I want to 'access' my external drive from my docker compose, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
container:
    image: container
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: container
    hostname: container
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - net-backend
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - F:\\Data:/data/local
      - app_data:/app/streama
```

And it's not working, so I've tried another ways to do it like:

```
volumes:
      - /F/Data:/data/local
```

or

```
volumes:
      - F:\Data:/data/local
```

or

```
volumes:
      - \\F\\Data:/data/local
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with `/f/Data:/data/local`